# How to store multiple values in a variable to be used in a case statement

Tags: oracle, variables

I am having this issue and any help in this regard will greatly be appreciated.
I have Oracle db and working with following business case:
An employee can work in a different job grades in his/her regular time hours or in overtime
Need to calculate employee’s hours w.r.t. different job grades and wage codes, because I have hours and job grades in different tables and the table which has job grades doesn’t have hours, instead time in and time out so after querying the db I get the following result.

| Emp_ID | Wage Code | Job grade | Hours | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 |  | 8 | 2021/06/07 |
| 1 | 02 | P | 2 | 2021/06/07 |
| 1 | 08 |  | 8 | 2021/06/08 |
| 1 | 01 |  | 6 | 2021/06/09 |
| 1 | 01 | E | 8 | 2021/06/09 |
| 1 | 01 |  | 8 | 2021/06/10 |
| 1 | 01 |  | 8 | 2021/06/11 |
| 1 | 02 |  | 9 | 2021/06/11 |

Now I get wrong hours when the employee works in different job grade(s).
To overcome this, I need to identify on which date employee worked in a different job grade do I can put case statement.
I used this logic.
Pick the date on which employee worked in different job grade and on that date do calculation of hours from table A
Other wise do calculation of hours from table B.
The problem is I can’t simply use variables because there could be multiple dates.
How can I achieve this? Can I use any other logic?

Thanks,

Here are my tables
TABLE A

| Emp_ID | Wage_code | time_in | time_out | Job_grade | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 |  | 8:00 | 16:00 |  | 2021-06-7 |
| 01 |  | 16:00 | 18:00 | P | 2021-06-7 |
| 01 |  | 8:00 | 16:00 |  | 2021-06-08 |
| 01 |  | 8:00 | 14:00 |  | 2021-06-09 |
| 01 |  | 14:00 | 16:00 | E | 2021-06-09 |
| 01 |  | 8:00 | 16:00 |  | 2021-06-10 |
| 01 |  | 8:00 | 16:00 |  | 2021-06-11 |
| 01 |  | 16:00 | 17:00 |  | 2021-06-11 |

This table doesn't store wage_codes. empty job_grade means employee has worked in the same job grade

TABLE B

| Emp_ID | Wage_code | Hours | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 8 | 2021-06-7 |
| 01 | 2 | 2 | 2021-06-7 |
| 01 | 8 | 8 | 2021-06-08 |
| 01 | 1 | 8 | 2021-06-09 |
| 01 | 1 | 8 | 2021-06-10 |
| 01 | 1 | 8 | 2021-06-11 |
| 01 | 2 | 2 | 2021-06-11 |

This table stores wage_codes but no job grade change, just a regular one and hours for each wage_code (1=regular,2=overtime,8=vacation etc..)

my query

```
select  
A.emp_id,
A.job_grade,
B.Wage_code,
B.Date,
case 
when A.job_grade ='' then B.Hours
else 
to_char(A.time_in - A.time_out) *(24),'fm99.90') 
end "Hours"

 from A 
left join B on A.emp_id=B.emp_id and A.Date=B.Date
```

With this query I get wrong hours when employee has worked in a different job grade. Because the condition in case statement checks if job grade is empty then calculate hours from Table B. Now e.g. on 06/07, employee has worked in a normal grade as well as in a different job grade.
How can I identify the date on which employee has worked in a different job grade so I can combine it with the job_grade condition in case statement and calculate hours accurately.

Many thanks for your support!!

Comment: Please provide all the mentioned tables and their relationships with the sample data (as `insert` or in plain text format) via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68433721/edit). And include your current query the desired results for this sample data.

Comment: Thanks astentx! I have edited and provided the details. Thanks!